# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 75720002

Tags: java

i am creating a server-client application where the server sends a pdf file to the all connected clients. The problem is i get this error and i searched for a solution but couldn`t get any. This is the error

```
 java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 75720002
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:782)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:279)
    at StudentThread.run(StudentThread.java:102)
```

Here is the server sending code:

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        String modifiedSentence;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
        inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream())), true);
        //String sentence;
        System.out.println("TeachID. "+id);
        modifiedSentence = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Student "+id+" says:"+modifiedSentence);
        arrS=modifiedSentence.split(" ");
        out.println("Hello "+arrS[2]+","+id);   
        studName=arrS[2];
        ((DefaultListModel) Teacher.made_list.getModel()).addElement(studName);

        while( true )
        {
            modifiedSentence = in.readLine();
            arrS=modifiedSentence.split(" ");
            if(arrS[0].equals("AcceptFile"))
            {
                try
                {
                    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    byte[] buffer = (byte[])ois.readObject();
                    String pic="copyServer"+id+".pdf";
                    System.out.println(pic);
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pic);
                    fos.write(buffer);  
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Exception writing");
                }

            }

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
        }
    }
}
public void sendF(String fn,Teacher teach)
{
    try{
        out.println("AcceptFile,");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()) ;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fn);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(buffer);
        //ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()) ;
        oos.writeObject(buffer);
        oos.flush();
        fis.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void sendThread(String elem, Teacher teach)
{

    out.println(elem);
    //System.out.println ("Thread id is " + this.id);
    System.out.println(this.socket.getInetAddress());
}
```

Here is the client receiving code:

```
public void run() 
{
    try
    {

        out=new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println("Hello Server "+name+",");

        String modifiedSentence;
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( socket.getInputStream() ) );
        modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println( modifiedSentence );

        arrT=modifiedSentence.split(",");
        if(arrT[0].equals("Hello "+name))
        {
            studId=Integer.parseInt(arrT[2]);
            System.out.println("My Id="+studId);
        }

        while( true )
        {
            modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
            System.out.println( modifiedSentence );

            arrT=modifiedSentence.split(",");
            if(arrT[0].equals("AcceptFile"))
            {
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                byte[] buffer = (byte[])ois.readObject();
                String pic="copyServer"+studId+".gif";
                System.out.println(pic);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pic);
                fos.write(buffer);  
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            }
    }
}
catch( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using the socket stream at all before those parts on the server and/or client?

Comment: yes, i am using it at both the client and the server.

Comment: if you're using it before the code parts you've posted, then you're doing something wrong there (unbalanced read/write probably). we can't guess.

Comment: yes i am using it in to read and write but how could they be unbalanced?

Comment: can't know without seeing the code

Comment: @Mat here is the code where i used the socket.

Answer (score 4):

`BufferedReader` can buffer more data from the socket than you've read yet. So on the client side, the header of your `byte[]` has probably already been read and buffered by your `inFromServer` reader, and will not be available to your `ObjectInputStream`.

Don't do that kind of thing. Either do all your marshaling "manually" (using the `PrintWriter`/`BufferedReader` pair), or do it all with object serialization with `ObjectOutputStream`/`ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: So if i am gonna use the BufferedReader as it is what i am using to read the server`s output,how to use it to write the file sent?

Comment: you'll need to do it manually if you go that route, i.e. probably first write the file size (either as an int or a string), then the bytes by using one of the PrintWriter.write methods.

Comment: but the PrintWriter writes only char or int or string and i need to write bytes or object (the pdf file). How could that be done?

Comment: PrintWriter's not meant to do that. If you want to do it you'll have to convert your data to a char array, which probably won't work. So PrintWriter is not the best option. You'll need less work to get your current code to work with only serialization.

Comment: @Mat you mean use ObjectOut an InputStream?