# Deserialize an Object from string without original object info in Java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Say I have an object serialized string that looks something like this when displayed in terminal:

```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```

This is the hex I see when typing:
`xxd -p fileName` in Terminal. I can also view it as Binary but I'm not sure how to decode the serialized object.

I know it is a set of Java serialized objects, but I don't know where the serialization starts/ends. I've tried to loop through with a start and end index but I keep getting:
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 30303061

I don't know what else to try, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Just to verify: Is what you want to show in your post actually mostly unprintable non-alpha-num noise? The problem is that what you see might be different from what I/we see, because of charactersets, unicode, ... I recommend to state that what you want to show is mostly unreadable. I realise that your question might be exactly about this, but a simple explanation/statement probably helps with the clarity. (downvote not by me, I only want to help)

Comment: See [java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 75720002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315247/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-stream-header-75720002). Also, please show us your code.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I meant that thats what I see when I type less "filename" in terminal. I can read it as hex/binary and ive tried all this but I am not sure how to approach the problem

Comment: `0x303061` is two ASCII spaces followed by a lowercase `a`. `String` is not a container for binary data. *Why* don't you know where the Serialization starts and ends? How was this data produced?

Comment: I am doing research under a professor, the student before me produced a .jar file that sends this data over a socket. I was wondering if there was any way to decode this data without having the source code

Comment: OK, so scan the data for the object stream header sequence, which I believe is 0xCAFEBABE, but you will find it specified in the Protocol chapter of the Object Serialization Specification. You should have taken a hex dump, and posted it here, not the gibberish.

Comment: NB This file does not start with `0x30303061`. Can't see those three spaces and an `a` anywhere.

Comment: Revised to hexdump as per suggestions, however I did not find either 0xCAFEBABE or 0x30303061 when scanning through the file, will try looking for those patterns in binary and get back to you

Comment: Justification as to thought process in previous comment: I do not know when the start and end of each object came in, therefore I feel it is possible that the binary wasn't aligned correctly with each hex value, maybe the binary is shifted over 1 or 2 bits which would make the hex output garbled

Comment: Shifted over 1 or 2 bits *how?* One thing is for sure, this is not serialized data. *Nor* is it the data that produced the `invalid stream header: 30303061` message. Try again. And post the code you are using to deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to deserialize the object. After some research I went through the hex dump step by step to extract relevant information. The tricky part is that some of the data is sent in different packets over HTTP so the deserialization is kind of stitched together. Anyway here is what I was able to come up with. If anyone has any input on the unknown parts of the snippet below, please, do not hesitate to comment and I will attempt to edit my answer accordingly.

```
0005 – STREAM_VERSION 
0a - UNKNOWN
73 – TC_OBJECT
72 – TC_CLASSDESC
0015 – length of the class name
616461732e746f6f6c6b69742e646174612e504144 - class name
efbfbd221844efbf – SerialVersionUID
bdefbfbdefbfbdefbfbd - UNKNOWN
02 - OBJECT SERIALIZABLE
0004 - NUMBER OF PROPERTIES (4)
44 - PROPERTY CODE (D : Double)

0001 - PROPERTY NAME LENGTH
61 - PROPERTY NAME (a)?

44 - PROPERTY CODE (D : Double)
0001 - PROPERTY NAME LENGTH 
64 - PROPERTY NAME (d)

44 - PROPERTY CODE (D : Double)
0001 - PROPERTY NAME LENGTH 
70 - PROPERTY NAME (p)

44 - PROPERTY CODE (D : Double)
0008 - PROPERTY NAME LENGTH 
73657175656e6365 - PROPERTY NAME (sequence)
0a -UNKNOWN
78 - END BLOCK

70efbfbdefbfbdef - VALUE OF a: 1.00947731285363886197528984273E236 
bfbd2b020c49efbf - VALUE OF d: -1.13937500000189637083813920526E-1 
bdefbfbdefbfbd45 - VALUE OF p: -2.3100431973060554004134169949E-10 
efbfbdefbfbdefbf - VALUE OF sequence: -1.9249974767166909849440370334E230
```

I hope this helps someone who is in the same situation as I was.

Thank you!

Helpful links:

[Javaworld](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2072752/the-java-serialization-algorithm-revealed.html)

[Javapapers](https://javapapers.com/core-java/java-serialization/)

Comment: Not accepting this answer since it only gives partial understanding.